# Concept of physical rewards for regular Stack Overflow users

Tags: discussion, feature-request, reputation, merchandise

I know it's always a good idea to contribute to sites like SO even if you are not getting any benefits because sites like these should be promoted.

But wouldn't it be a good idea if **regular users with high reputation** could earn physical rewards like SO tee-shirts, caps etc. I remember last season mascots were awarded to all users but these were only virtual. I suggest something like the following:

- 1000 points => A tee-shirt with SO printed on it applauding the user
- 5000 points => A geek cap with SO printed

etc.

This can promote a healthy competition.

Comment: At that reputation you haven't given SE nearly enough ad impressions to pay for a t-shirt. They'd be losing money

Answer (score 9):

The community management team *already* sends goodies to users they feel deserve an extra pat on the back.

Just continue to contribute to your community, go the extra mile, and perhaps you too will receive an offer of a T-shirt.

This is not connected to reputation, and never should be. People can contribute to their communities *without* vying for reputation, and can make a huge difference that should be recognized. Help clean up the tags, answer questions on your per-site meta, expose cheaters. You know, the janitorial tasks that *need doing*?